# Drawing multiple sprite images on the HTML5

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, sprite

Currently I have put some functions together into a class. So it will be easier for me to store inside an array for multiple drawing of the sprite images. However is there a method that I can draw them out manually, instead of I set it through the array outprint and it draw it out automatically? Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Fish Animation</title>
  <style type='text/css'>
    canvas  {border:1px solid; background-color:#EFEFEF;}
  </style>

<script type='text/javascript'>
window.onload=function(){
var canvas = document.getElementById('pondCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
polyFillRAFNow() ;

var frameCount = 8 ; 
var frameWidth, frameHeight ; 
var frameScale = 0.4 ; 

var animIndex = 0 ;
var animFrames = [0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 6, 5, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1];

var xPos = canvas.width / 2, 
yPos = canvas.height / 2;
var speedX;
var speedY;
var speedXSign;
var speedYSign;
var fishes = [];
var anotherFish;

function Fish(xPos, yPos, speedX, speedY, imgFish, frameWidth, frameHeight) {
    this.image = imgFish;
    this.xPos = canvas.width / 2;
    this.yPos = canvas.height / 2;
    this.speedX = speedX;
    this.speedY = speedY;
    this.frameWidth = frameWidth;
    this.frameHeight = frameHeight;
    this.frameCount = 8;
    this.frameScale = 0.4;
    this.animIndex = 0;
    this.animFrames = [0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 6, 5, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1];
}

Fish.prototype.changeDirection = function () {
    speedXSign = this.speedX > 0 ? 1 : -1;
    speedYSign = this.speedY > 0 ? 1 : -1;
    this.speedX = speedXSign * (1 + Math.random() * 1.7);
    this.speedY = speedYSign * (1 + Math.random() * 2);
};

Fish.prototype.move = function () {
this.animIndex++;
    if ( this.animIndex == animFrames.length) this.animIndex = 0;

    this.xPos += this.speedX;
    if ((this.xPos + this.frameWidth * this.frameScale / 1.8) >= canvas.width || 
        (this.xPos - this.frameWidth * this.frameScale / 1.8) <= 0) {
        this.speedX = -this.speedX;
    }

    this.yPos += this.speedY;
    if ((this.yPos + this.frameHeight * frameScale / 1.8) >= canvas.height || 
        (this.yPos - this.frameHeight * frameScale / 1.8) <= 0) {
        this.speedY = -this.speedY;
    }
};

Fish.prototype.drawFish = function () {
    context.save();
    context.translate(this.xPos, this.yPos);
    var speedXSign = this.speedX > 0 ? 1 : -1;
    var speedYSign = this.speedY > 0 ? 1 : -1;
    context.scale(speedXSign, speedYSign);
    var frameIndex = animFrames[this.animIndex];
    context.drawImage(imgFish, frameIndex * this.frameWidth, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight,
                    -frameWidth * frameScale / 2, -this.frameHeight * this.frameScale / 2, 
                        this.frameWidth * this.frameScale, this.frameHeight * this.frameScale);
    context.restore();
};

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for (var i = 0; i < fishes.length; i++){
        var fish = fishes[i];
        fish.changeDirection();
        fish.move();
        fish.drawFish();
    }
}

var imgFish = new Image();
imgFish.onload = init;
imgFish.src = 'http://dl.dropbox.com/s/4x14mv75dx7bmi5/FishStrip.png';

function init() {
    frameWidth = imgFish.width / frameCount ; 
    frameHeight = imgFish.height ; 

    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        var anotherFish = new Fish(xPos, yPos, speedX, speedY, imgFish, frameWidth, frameHeight);
        fishes.push(anotherFish);
        anotherFish.drawFish();
    }
    animate();
}

function polyFillRAFNow() {
    var w = window,
        foundRequestAnimationFrame = w.requestAnimationFrame || w.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || w.msRequestAnimationFrame || w.mozRequestAnimationFrame || w.oRequestAnimationFrame || function (cb)     {
            setTimeout(cb, 1000 / 60);
        };
    window.requestAnimationFrame = foundRequestAnimationFrame;
    }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="pondCanvas" width="1024" height="600">
        Canvas is not supported.
    </canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: In fact this issue has nothing specific to the canvas. It's about handling objects. You have to store all data relative to one fish in a single object, store all instances of your fishes inside an array, then iterate on this array to update and draw the fish inside animate. Seek tutorials on Objects and Array.

Comment: Yes, I have working on the example code by storing all function into class. I have just edit the codes on top to the latest on and it's able to draw out multiple fishes when I set it using the array output. But is there any method for me to draw it out manually?

Comment: Rename your move() to changeDirection(), and newAnimationFrame() to move(). Call changeDirection with something like :  if (Math.random()>0.995) fish.changeDirection();  so that it only changes from time to time. And now your code is perfect, i don't get your question.

Comment: 1 ) If you could just be more precise about 'a button or something' :-) 2) share the fiddle link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding fishes manually:

HTML:

```
<button id="button" > Add a fish! </button>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {

        var anotherFish = new Fish(xPos, yPos, speedX, speedY, imgFish, frameWidth, frameHeight);
        fishes.push(anotherFish);
        anotherFish.drawFish();

    animate();
};
```

Your code is there, I just copied it and put it in an even listener.